# Issue with IIS 7.5 in Internet Explorer on Windows Server 2008 R2 (Certificate Issue?)

Tags: php, internet-explorer, iis

At the company I work for, we are running a web server using Internet Information Services 7.5. Until today, my addition to it has been living on my PC. After a little fumbling and digging, I was able to get everything running (seemingly) flawlessly. However, I've come across a weird error, one which I have spent a total of 4 hours searching for and trying to fix, all to no avail. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but the issue is:

In Internet Explorer, and ONLY in Internet Explorer, the web site displays strange.

[image]

Now, what's odd is, this issue only happens when I do documents/giganet (which is what the site is pointed to). We also have another web application called Enlighten, installed on the same server, running (as it would seem) all of the same configurations. It does not give this error. When viewed in Firefox or Chrome, even under the same URL (documents/giganet), this error does not happen. It views just fine.

Interestingly, if I go to the server domain directly (server-mail.domain-hybrid/giganet), it works fine in all browsers, including IE.

How is that possible and what can I do about it?

Thank you.

NOTE: I thought that this could be a certificate issue originally, but all attempts to rectify that were for naught as well. I have the "giganet" web application under the Default Web Site, can't seem to get it to run if it's its own site (Enlighten is also underneath this Default Web Site and functions flawlessly). There was something I could try which involved me creating a self-signed certificate and then applying it to the bindings, but I can't do that with the web application by itself. I could apply it to the Default Web Site, but according to the popup box I get, it would overwrite what's already in place, which I very much do not want to do.

I'm open to any suggestions or ideas.

Comment: what certificate? the url in the picture appears to be `http://`, so there's no SSL and therefore no certificate.

Comment: It's IE 9 I think. And I don't know about the certificate thing, as I said that was just me taking a stab in the dark. I don't know what the issue is. Or how to fix it. That's why I'm asking for help is because I'm completely and utterly lost.

Comment: Let me toss something out there then... Are you PCI compliant? If so, did you turn off TLS 1.0? If you did, understand that IE 8-10 do not support anything higher than that and would fail to work with your SSL

Comment: Everything is compliant and no I have not turned anything off. That solution would still beg the question, why does it still work when accessed directly? But thanks. I'm still looking stuff up as I wait for responses here, so I'm not just expecting a solution to slap me in the face, although that would be nice.

Comment: Taking a closer look at it, it seems like it's the CSS and the jQuery that aren't working. But the permissions for those are set fine...

Comment: Nevermind! I got it. Turns out it was an issue with Compatibility View. It automatically was loading in in Compat-View since it was on an intranet network. Ticked off that box under Tools and then bam, it worked fine. Thank you all anyway though.

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with IE9. When you're running it on a local intranet web site, it automatically switches to Compatibility View. Turn that checkbox off and you're good. Can't believe I spent hours researching that.